# Using cyclone or tornado in python, how do i make a simple handler that responds with json?

Tags: python, json, tornado

Do i do it like this?

```
import cyclone

class MyHandler(cyclone.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self, command):
        details = {'status':'success'}
        json = json_encode(details)
        self.write(json)
```

Or is there more to it than that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's even less than that: You can simply use `self.write(details)` if it you write a dict, it will be automatically converted to JSON.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend to use the built in [json encoder function](https://github.com/facebook/tornado/blob/master/tornado/escape.py) :

```
self.write(tornado.escape.json_encode(details)
```

If the details is of type dict, tornado will json encode the data automatically. This is not true for lists.
From the Tornado code (web.py):

> Note that lists are not converted to
>   JSON because of a potential cross-site
>   security vulnerability. All JSON
>   output should be wrapped in a
>   dictionary. More details at
>   http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/20/anatomy-of-a-subtle-json-vulnerability.aspx